# How to start XWindow on Fedora20

Tags: linux, fedora, x11

I am just installed Fedora20 in VMWare. my computer is win8 64bit. But I can't start Xwindow.
I already login root. try "startx". "command not found". what's mean.How to start Xwindow on Fedora20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have X installed, and everything is more or less "out of the box", then you can shift to runlevel 5.

```
 init 5
```

Note that it must be ran as the root user.

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention what type of install it was.  Providing the X Windows system was installed, you can check the inittab settings by sudo vi /etc/inittab (or cat /etc/inittab if you just want to view it)
You are looking for the last line.  It should say " id:5:initdefault:  "   
In order for Gnome/KDE/etc to load when Fedora  starts.

If you  edit the file to change the last line,  reboot the system and it should open the graphical login.